# Параметр opcache.revalidate_freq = 2, требуется 0

Tags: php, битрикс

Камрады, помогите. Провожу тестирование системы на Bitrix, в результате выводится сообщение об ошибке "

> Параметр opcache.revalidate_freq = 2, требуется 0

", пытался дописать в .htaccess строку `php_value opcache.revalidate_freq 0`. Не помогло

Comment: в ini меняйте..

Comment: Так нет такого) В этом и суть)

Comment: @teran А нет, разобрался, спасибо, что потратили время

Answer (score 0):

Открой
`Рабочий стол -> Настройки -> Инструменты -> Диагностика -> настройка php`

В
`Zend OPcache`
будет строка
`opcache.revalidate_freq    2   2`
Тебе нужно поменять настройку окружения, поменять [это значение](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=32&LESSON_ID=20402).